# Allowed cgroup devices for libvirt/lxc container

Tags: fedora, libvirt, lxc, cgroup

I want to allow my libvirt/lxc containers to use tun/tap device. In order to do so I for a running container I can add it to the allowed devices by:

```
# echo "c 10:200 rwm" > /sys/fs/cgroup/devices/libvirt/lxc/client-1/devices.allow
```

resulting in:

```
# cat /sys/fs/cgroup/devices/libvirt/lxc/client-1/devices.list
c 1:3 rwm
c 1:5 rwm
c 1:7 rwm
c 1:8 rwm
c 1:9 rwm
c 5:0 rwm
c 5:2 rwm
c 136:* rwm
c 10:200 rwm
```

However I'm having some difficulties on making this the default setting for every container.

Googling shows that changing **/etc/cgconfig.conf** to

```
group libvirt/lxc {
    devices {
            devices.allow="c 10:200 rwm";
    }
}
```

should fix, but it doesn't (even after restarting the involved services -libvirtd, cgconfig- in every possible order)

Played around a bit with the **cgroup.clone_children** setting but it doesn't help.

**My Questions are:**

1 How to add this device as a default allow for every libvirt/lxc container?

2 What process is responsible for the default allowed list?

```
c 1:3 rwm
c 1:5 rwm
c 1:7 rwm
c 1:8 rwm
c 1:9 rwm
c 5:0 rwm
c 5:2 rwm
c 136:* rwm
```

All packages are from an up-to-date Fedora 18 system.

Answer (score 3):

libvirt_lxc populates the guest's `/dev` tree on startup according to the guest's configuration. The [documentation](http://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsHostDevCaps) says you have to put the configuration in the guest's XML configuration file. Use a `hostdev` with the "misc" `type` and with its `source` pointing to a `char` device at `/dev/net/tun`.

The snippet should look like this:

```
...
<devices>
    ...
    <hostdev mode='capabilities' type='misc'>
        <source>
            <char>/dev/net/tun</char>
        </source>
    </hostdev>
</devices>
...
```

To edit the guest's XML file use `virsh`. For a local instance use this command:

```
virsh -c lxc:/// edit GUESTNAME
```

I can confirm this working with libvirt-1.2.1.